# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The create a Rails app on my machine and push the project to github, but unable to deploy the application on Heroku. The incompatible issue is gone, but sqlite issue remains. I just updated the error and gem file as follow. Please, help me!

Error:

```
          An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot co
ntinue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:blazing-mountain-6037.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blazing-mountain-6037.git'
```

My Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

enter code here
```

Comment: Which version of bundler are you using on your development machine?

Comment: PS - it's worth mentioning that Heroku are experiencing potential [platform issues](https://status.heroku.com/) right now. Even their own website is down. Virtually every heroku app I know of is down at the moment, including the [Richard Dawkins Foundation](http://richarddawkinsfoundation.org/) website and the [RailsTutorial](http://railstutorial.org/) one. What have you done? You broke it ;) I've never seen this level of outage on their network before.

Answer (score 1):

Try using rails 3.2.6, and upgrading bundler to 1.2.0.pre on your dev machine

Comment: now I got this error
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot co
ntinue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:blazing-mountain-6037.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blazing-mountain-6037.git'

Comment: Hmm, Heroku should not be giving you an error about sqlite if you have it inside your development group, and they're running `bundle --without development:test`, which, I see from your logs, they are. Very odd.

Comment: Did you run `bundle update rails` and do `git commit -am 'bundling'` before pushing to heroku? If not, then they will create their own Gemfile.lock, and it's possible that this process ignores their own directive to bundle without development and test envirnments.

Comment: I just did what u told me, but still have the same error. It seems that it's not able to install sqlite3

Comment: You have changed your Gemfile from what you had orignally. You have removed your development group from it. You want sqlite to be inside a `group :development do` block like you had before. That will fix this problem.